# bootstrap-datepicker: Show DIV when selecting specific date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

Using the [bootstrap-datepicker plugin](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the embedded markup...

How to show/reveal a DIV element when selecting a specific date AND hide it again when another date has been selected?

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #example {
      display: none;
      color: green;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">Yay my favorate day!</div>
  Please select <b>11/07/2017</b> to show an example:
  <br />
  <div id="myCalendar"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput">

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#myCalendar').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        weekStart: 1,
        maxViewMode: 2,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
        todayHighlight: true
      }).on('changeDate', function() {
        $('#hiddenInput').val(
          $('#myCalendar').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );
      }).change(function() {
        $("#example").toggle($(this).val() === "11-07-2017");
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

## [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4skcs52y/1/)

Comment: I use slideUp/slideDown for showing/hiding elements on events as an example. Writing something to show/hide a div or other element when an event occurs (like the ID of the div equalling the date selected, for example) is possible.

Comment: What did you try so far? Rember that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @VincenzoC I have updated my question to show what I am working with so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event, as the [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#events) says:

> All events have extra data attached to the event object that is passed to any event handlers
>
> - `date`: the relevant Date object, in local timezone. For a multidate picker, this will be the latest date picked.

You can check what is the selected day (using setter like `getDate()`, `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()`) and the using jQuery [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Here a live sample:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myCalendar').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    weekStart: 1,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    todayHighlight: true
  }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    if( e.date && e.date.getDate() == 7 &&
        e.date.getMonth() == 10 && 
        e.date.getFullYear() == 2017 ){
      $("#example").show();
    } else {
      $("#example").hide();
    }
    $('#hiddenInput').val(
      $('#myCalendar').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
    );
  });
});
```

```css
#example {
  display: none;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">Yay my favorate day!</div>
Please select <b>11/07/2017</b> to show an example:
<br />
<div id="myCalendar"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput">
```

Comment: That's neat. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking the value of the `datepicker`.  For this example I use `11/07/2017` as the date you are checking for (aka November 17th, 2017).

```js
$(function(){
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
    }).change(function () {
      $("#example").toggle($(this).val() === "11-07-2017");
    });
});
```

```css
#example {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">Yay my favorate day!</div>
Please select <b>11/07/2017</b> to show an example:
<br />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Date..." name="date">
```

Comment: How is it done with the embedded version (without the input field)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for different frameworks (and vanilla js). For example, an easy one, if you are using angularjs (not much javascript code is required):

```
<input data-provide="datepicker" ng-model='yourdate'>
<div id='divExample' ng-show='yourdate==somevalue'></div>
```